# Sendgrid email going into spam in Django Web App

Tags: django, email, gmail, sendgrid, spam

I am using sendgrid for email service on my personal website. The mail is delivering successfully. But, instead of going into the inbox, it goes into spam in gmail. I am using Django framework with SendGrid-django package which is a simple django backend to send email using SendGrid's Web API.

Please provide me a solution to get them into the inbox. I am using a from address like : noreply@mywebsitedomain.com

Comment: Look at the raw email (the headers) to see what caused it to go to spam. Whether it's your mail client or your mail provider that marked it as spam. In general, `noreply` scores high on the spam filters, but isn't the only reason to mark as spam.

Comment: Also, make sure you setup the DNS records for your domain correctly (DKIM and spf).

Comment: You may send your mail to an id given by [mail-tester](http://mail-tester.com) and they will give you a score and issues.

Comment: Many of SendGrids shared ip addresses are blacklisted from time to time. You can check the status on public blacklists of the ip your domain have been assigned on services like mxtoolbox.com